# Is Spring batch in memory job repository good for production?

Tags: spring-batch

Can you use in memory job repository in production if you are not looking for restarts of the job?

If yes, then does it have any impact on memory?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The in memory job repository is intended for test purposes only (it says it in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html).  For production use, we recommend an in memory database such as HSQLDB.

Comment: The reason I want to  use inmemory is that I saw performance issue when it has to aggregate response from oracle db in case of master slave design

Comment: Can I also use embedded hsql db in case of remote partitioning? If yes then how does slave will locate the step? Does that mean, slave has to connect to master node for hsql db ?

Comment: For remote partitioning, you need a real database.

Comment: If I use oracle for spring batch schema then I saw a performance issue when master step taking almost 10 min to insert step execution data in db and sending message to queue and once all steps are completed again master step takes more then 10 min to process aggregated response.

Comment: All slaves need access to the job repository when using remote partitioning so there isn't any real alternative there.  With regards to the performance issues, are you sure it's the insert that's the issue or is it the processing within the partitioner?  Without being able to see the code, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: I did confirm that partitioners are finishing their work and updating step context back to table with status COMPLETED. I was debugging code MessageChannelPartitionHandler and noticed that there is one thread which aggregates the response back. In our case that aggegation comes from polling db and counting completed steps with what master step sent. Most of the time was spent on aggregating this responses buy polling db query. Now as far as db performance is concerned, we confirm it is working fine since our biz tables are in same schema as batch.